# Is there a formula for upcoming date using formula in Google sheet based on condition?

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, recurrence

I have a google sheet where I need to get the next upcoming date based on the start date set in column A

Any pointers are greatly appreciated? I am unable exhibit the efforts as I am completely new to this sort of recurrence using Google sheets

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1g_UNg4MjDy3gFufpjZtMRkbBz80K3scQdZOaiAnZi7I/edit#gid=0

[image]

Comment: You mention*"next upcoming date based on the start date set in column A"*. But under `Frequency` you have "Daily" and under `description` "every 2 days". Could you share the expected results instead of `?`? And does the `Count` play any part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior (the next date from today including today) could be implemented manually by this formula:

```
={
  "Next date from today";
  ARRAYFORMULA(
    IFS(
      A2:A >= TODAY(),
        A2:A,
      B2:B = "Daily",
        TODAY() + MOD(TODAY() - A2:A, C2:C),
      B2:B = "Weekly",
        TODAY() + MOD(TODAY() - A2:A, 7 * C2:C),
      B2:B = "Monthly",
        EDATE(A2:A, ROUNDUP((12 * (YEAR(TODAY()) - YEAR(A2:A)) + (MONTH(TODAY()) - MONTH(A2:A)) - IF(DAY(TODAY()) < DAY(A2:A), 1, 0)) / C2:C, 0) * C2:C),
      True,
        ""
    )
  )
}
```

For additional options (like "every 2nd monday of the month" and others) additional options should be implemented in that `IFS` part.

[image]

If you are interested in a trivial case where the next date from the start date (column `F:F` on the screenshot) is needed, then the formula would be much simpler:

```
={
  "Next date";
  ARRAYFORMULA(
    IFS(
      B2:B = "Daily",
        A2:A + C2:C,
      B2:B = "Weekly",
        A2:A + 7 * C2:C,
      B2:B = "Monthly",
        EDATE(A2:A, C2:C),
      True,
        ""
    )
  )
}
```

Again, for additional options you'll need to add corresponding part to the `IFS`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [IFS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7014145) to check `Frequency`, and:

- If `Daily`, add `Count` value to start date.
- If `Weekly`, add `Count` value multiplied by 7.
- If `Monthly`, since not all months have the same duration, retrieve the `YEAR`, `MONTH` and `DAY` indexes, add `Count` to the [MONTH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093052) index, and set a new [DATE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092969), **EDIT**: or as suggested by [kishkin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/279806/kishkin), use [EDATE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092974).

It could be something like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(IFS(
    B2:B = "Daily", A2:A + C2:C,
    B2:B = "Weekly", A2:A + 7 * C2:C,
    B2:B = "Monthly", EDATE(A2:A,C2:C)
)))
```

[image]

Comment: hey! Thought you had an error in __Monthly__ case, and should've used `EDATE` (which is more compact), but it appears that you actually can give the second parameter to the `DATE` function bigger that 12 - it will increase the year accordingly. That is cool! Will go check the same about day part... :)

Comment: `DATE(2000, 1, 32)` does work as expected - gives you the 1st of February.

Comment: Hi @kishkin, thank you for your comment! I agree that `EDATE` would be more appropriate for this case, even if both solutions work here. I updated my answer based on this. Thank you again.