# How to check whether day satisfies the recurrence condition using google sheet formula

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, recurrence

I have a Google sheet where it has startdate, frequency, count. I need to check whether the todays date is satisfying the recurrence and display TRUE if today() is satisfied and false if not satisfied.

This will help me determine each time, the sheet is opened I can find out from TODAY() date is satisifed or not?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/142od5eUib5nHmdi4mnENuPbh-Yn485NzUSt90p84QE0/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

Comment: Why not use the formula from your [LAST QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62374637/is-there-a-formula-for-upcoming-date-using-formula-in-google-sheet-based-on-cond) and see if it is `=TODAY()`: `=otherformula= TODAY()`

Comment: Unclear what logic would be used to test the criteria. Would help if you amended your photo to show the expected output given the data you have shown us and explain how you got there. Or, is there data somewhere else you have not shown us that is needed?

Comment: Let me revise the sheet data

Comment: This will be done differently depending on whether you want Google sheets or Excel.  Please choose which you will be using.

Comment: Google sheets. Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @Scott Craner said, just compare the result of the formula from the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62374637/is-there-a-formula-for-upcoming-date-using-formula-in-google-sheet-based-on-cond) with `TODAY()`:

```
={
  "Today is the day?";
  ARRAYFORMULA(
    IF(
      A2:A = "",
        ,
        IFS(
          A2:A >= TODAY(),
            A2:A,
          B2:B = "Daily",   
             TODAY() + MOD(TODAY() - A2:A, C2:C),
          B2:B = "Weekly",
            TODAY() + MOD(TODAY() - A2:A, 7 * C2:C),
          B2:B = "Monthly",
            EDATE(A2:A, ROUNDUP((12 * (YEAR(TODAY()) - YEAR(A2:A)) + (MONTH(TODAY()) - MONTH(A2:A)) - IF(DAY(TODAY()) < DAY(A2:A), 1, 0)) / C2:C, 0) * C2:C),
          True,
            ""
        ) = TODAY()
    )
  )
}
```

[image]